# Notify application icon using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make the application icon, in taskbar(windows) or dock(os x) to highlight, using javascript ?

When I say highlight, is like the jumping icon in os x.

What I need is when my web app receive a websocket message, the user knows that, 
even if he/she is using another application.

Comment: you may look at Html5 Notifications:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications

Comment: The Html5 notification is a good idea. Is not what I´m looking for, but could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do jumping icon animation analog via JavaScript. There is no such API. There are only 3 options:

1. [Sound](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html) notification
2. HTML5 [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/notification)
3. [Favicon update](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/)